# Proving the equivalence for the map given with wedge product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, differential-forms, products, exterior-algebra

Let $\alpha \in \Lambda^{p}L$, which is $p$-th power of $L$, where $L$ is linear space of dimension equal to $n$. Let us consider the following map $f_{\alpha} \colon L \rightarrow \Lambda^{p+1}L$ given with the formula $f_{\alpha}(\sigma)=\alpha \wedge \sigma$, where $\wedge$ is a wedge product.

Prove that if $\alpha, \beta \in \Lambda^{p}L$ and $p<n$, then:
$$f_{\alpha} = f_{\beta} \iff \alpha = \beta.$$

The part where we assume $\alpha = \beta$ is easy, but what about another implication? Does anything come your minds? This was the first thing I thought about:
$$\alpha_{1} \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha_{p} \wedge \sigma= \beta_{1} \wedge \dots \wedge \beta_{p} \wedge \sigma \iff (\alpha_{1} \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha_{p} - \beta_{1} \wedge \dots \wedge \beta_{p}) \wedge \sigma=0.$$I am stuck here, but maybe I don't see something very obvious about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $e_i$ be a basis for $L$, and assume $\alpha =\sum_I a_Ie_I$ where $I\subseteq \{1,2,\dots, n\}, \ |I|=p$ and $e_{\{i_1,\dots, i_p\}} =e_{i_1}\land\dots \land e_{i_p}$ with $i_1<\dots<i_p$.

We have to prove $f_{\alpha} =0 \implies \alpha=0$.

Assume some $a_I\ne 0$, then since $|I|=p<n$, there's an index $j\notin I$, and hence $a_I(e_I\land e_j)$ will be a nonzero term in $f_\alpha(e_j)$.

Comment: I don't think I understood your answer correctly. Why did you prove $f_{a} = 0 \implies \alpha = 0$ instead of one above?

Comment: It's based on your observation: $f_\alpha=f_\beta \iff f_{\alpha-\beta} =0 $.

Comment: Well, I am not still not convinced, could you please elaborate on this proof a little bit more? I clearly don't get something here and I don't know what it is yet.

Comment: How is it guaranteed that adding $e_{j}$ to our wedge product doesn't make the whole result zero? Is there any other case of it being zero aside from what's described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Alternating_product ?

Comment: What if $e_{j}$ is already created out of basis vectors used to create $p$-vector $\alpha$ as linear combination, for example?

Comment: Note that the basis $ e_i$ is fixed and $e_I$ is a basis for $\Lambda^pL$. So, there's a unique way to write $\alpha=\sum_Ia_Ie_I$. Multiply it by $e_j$: we'll receive a linear combination of elements $e_{I\cup\{j\}}$ where $j\notin I$, and these elements are still linearly independent.